# Why is SymLogNorm not creating a proper plot when using contour maps?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, matplotlib-basemap

Having some issues using the SymLogNorm section in mpl_toolkits.basemap. I want a log scaled contour plot with both negative and positive values in a log scale (hence using SymLogNorm). However, everytime I use it, I get a plot which only shows positive and negative values (see below). It works fine when using a scatter plot example, but not when plotting on a map.

[image]!

Any help as to how to get it to what I need would be greatly appriciated.

Cheers

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

lon = [-180,-140,-100,-60,-20,0,20,60,100,140,180]
lat = [90,70,50,30,10,-10,-30,-50,-70,-90]
bc = [[1,4,5,5,5,4,0.1,-0.2,-0.03,0,1],[0.1,1,1,0.8,-0.6,-0.005,0,0,-0.9,-0.004,-0.5],[0.7,0.07,0,0,0,0.6,0.1,-2.3,1,1,1.5],[1,1,0,-0.1,0,-0.5,1,1.2,2,11,3],[1,4,5,5,5,4,0.1,-0.2,-0.03,0,-0.9],[0.1,1,1,0.8,-0.6,-0.005,0,0,-0.9,-0.004,-0.08],[0.7,0.07,0,0,0,0.6,0.1,-2.3,1,1,0],[1,1,0,-0.1,0,-0.5,1,1.2,2,11,3],[1,1,0,-0.1,0,-0.5,1,1.2,2,11,2],[1,1,0,-0.1,0,-0.5,1,1.2,3,0,0.3]]
 #Draw Map
    # use low resolution coastlines.
map = Basemap(projection='cyl',lat_0=0.,lon_0=0,resolution='l')
    # draw coastlines, country boundaries, fill continents.
map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.75)
map.drawcountries(linewidth=0.25)
map.fillcontinents #(color='grey',lake_color='white')
# draw the edge of the map projection region 
map.drawmapboundary(fill_color='white')
    #draw lat/lon grid lines every 30 degrees.
map.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180,180,30)) 
map.drawparallels(np.arange(-90,90,30))

    #map completed, now ask which month you want data for
    #make grid on world map from the long/lat in the data (shape of bc)

lon, lat = np.meshgrid(lon, lat)    
    #make those the x and y axis, but in map form
x, y =map(lon,lat)


    #Clear plot and choose colour maps
plt.clf()
my_cmap = cm.get_cmap('brg')
tickld = [-10,-1,-1e-1,-1e3,1e3,1e-1,1,10]
norm=mpl.colors.SymLogNorm(linthresh=1e-4, vmin=-100, vmax=100)
#plot the filled contour map, using levels, colours and a log scale for the     colourbar
cs = map.contourf(x,y,bc,levels=tickld,cmap=my_cmap,norm = norm)

    #create the colour bounds for the colour map (same as for the plot)


cb1 = plt.colorbar(cmap=my_cmap, 
        norm=norm,
        extend='both',
        orientation="vertical",
        ticks=tickld,
        shrink = 0.38,
        fraction = 0.01)



    #add coastlines on top of plot
map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.75)
map.drawcountries(linewidth=0.25)
    #show plot
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!!!

SymLogNorm does not like using exponential of negative numbers as it's threshold.

To get round this, instead of putting something like 1e-4, put 0.0001 instead.

Simple, yet frustrating!!!